# why does google talk work with firefox but not with chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, gtalk

I have switched to Chrome because Firefox gets stopped with scripts not working (I don't know how to fix that issue). Chrome is OK except that google talk doesn't work. I would have to use hangout which doesn't work on my computer. I run Ubuntu 14.04 on a 6 years old mini dell 9 with 1Gb ram.
Firefox works fine with google talk. I'd rather use Firefox if I wouldn't have the frequent slowdowns with the scripts issue. I have ordered 2Gb of ram to see if it improves the running of the computer.

Comment: can you link the plugin which you are referring?

Comment: The plugin is called Google Talk

Answer (score 1):

You need to download and install the [Google Talk plugin](https://www.google.com/tools/dlpage/hangoutplugin?hl=en) for Ubuntu :

1. Download the right package for your configuration [here](https://www.google.com/tools/dlpage/hangoutplugin/download.html?hl=en).
2. Install it with a graphical package manager (Ubuntu Software Center, Synaptic, etc...) or run :

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i google-talkplugin_current_*.deb
   ```

---

Then authorize the plugin to be run every time you use Google Talk :

1. Open your Google Talk page
2. In the upper right corner, click **Plug-in blocked** or the puzzle piece icon with a red **X**. and select :

> Always allow plug-ins on mail.google.com: Allows you to keep making
>   voice calls with Google Chat.

I hope this is what you talked about...

Comment: isn't he talking about a browser plugin?

Comment: hum... Maybe I do not understand his question properly then...

Comment: well..mine is a guess :-)

Comment: Google talk is installed otherwise I could not use it in Firefox, and I can but not in Chrome

Comment: Are you sure you allowed the execution of the plugin ?